# What is the largest subgroup of Z contained in 10Z and 2Z?

Tags: group-theory

I know this is really easy but I can't find anything to confirm my answer in any notes and the fact this is 4 marks throws me off.

Is it simply just 2Z? As 10Z is just the integers that are multiples of 10 and 14Z multiples of 14?

Comment: Is 2Z contained in 10Z?

Comment: right, read it again and i have to find the LCM then?

Comment: @AnoUser1 that's right

Answer (score 2):

The other way around:  $10\Bbb Z\subset 2\Bbb Z$.

In general it would be $\operatorname{lcm}(m,n)\Bbb Z$ is the largest subgroup of $m\Bbb Z$ and $n\Bbb Z$.